# how to get date and month column using object model database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I have add static date in database sqlite and i have get this date and month column using object model and date and month wise set notification suppose today is 4 people birthday i have notification this 4 people name but error i have pass object to get date and month column so getting error

**My database Column**

```
DataType
TEXT                    Integer   Integer
Name                     dd         mm
"Indira Gandhi"         "19"        11
"Bal Gangadhar Tilak"   "23"        7
"Mangal Pandey"         "19"        7
```

**Notification.java**

```
People people = new People();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        String str_date = people.getDate();
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "strDate" + str_date);
        String str_month = people.getMonth();
        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date, month;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
        date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "str_date" + date);
        month = (Date) formatter.parse(str_month);
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "str_month" + month);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.setTime(month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.setTime(month);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Notification.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Notification.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Notification.this.getSystemService(Notification.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

**MyReceiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationOpen.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.birthday_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Alert Me!")
            .setContentText("Today is Birthday").setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotifyBuilder.build());


}
```

**DataBaseHelper**

```
 public List<People> getPeopleDate() {
    List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from people", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String peopleImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_IMAGE));
            String peopleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_NAME));

            String peopleDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_DATE));
            String peopleMonth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_MONTH));
            String peopleYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_YEAR));

            People people = new People();

            people.setPeopleImage(peopleImage);
            people.setPeopleName(peopleName);

            people.setDate(peopleDate);
            people.setMonth(peopleMonth);
            people.setYear(peopleYear);

            peoples.add(people);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", e.getMessage());
    }
    return peoples;
}
```

**People.class**

```
public class People implements Serializable {
private String peopleImage;
private String peopleName;
private String id;
private String month, date, year;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setPeopleName(String peopleName) {
    this.peopleName = peopleName;
}

public String getPeopleName() {
    return peopleName;
}

public void setPeopleImage(String peopleImage) {
    this.peopleImage = peopleImage;
}

public String getPeopleImage() {
    return peopleImage;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you are trying to convert "November " to int. Which is not possible.

Comment: November is already to int in static database check update Qu. @DheerubhaiBansal

Comment: @JaydeepDhamecha Please share People class and full description of People table

Comment: okay i will  share

Comment: check my people class @JayPrakashKumar

Comment: @JaydeepDhamecha i think you are sharing half of class and table please share full

Comment: how can you store string value in Integer type in mm.

Comment: forgot all store months as number wise like november as 11 and so on. It will work.

Comment: mm is TEXT formate sorry about this @DheerubhaiBansal

Comment: Its too much. You have write in first comment mm is int, now is text. How can you convert "November" to int. I think not possible.

Comment: how can do this for my code @DheerubhaiBansal

Comment: either make column as int and store month by numbering or If you do'nt want to change column type then store as "November" to "11" ans so on.

Comment: But i have to Display  november is text format so ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126058/discussion-between-dheerubhai-bansal-and-jaydeep-dhamecha).

Comment: This Question is quite convoluted, and complicated by way too much code and irrelevant details. Please boil this down to the bare minimum to focus on the core of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Month name to integer

Your Question and code are quite convoluted, but you seem to be hung up on storing month as text by its name in English.

Firstly, don't do this, don't store a month by its name. Use a plain integer, 1-12 for January-December.

But if you must, you can convert an English name of month to a `Month` enum object, as the enum objects happen to be defined with labels in English. From that `Month` object ask for the integer month number.

```
Month m = Month.valueOf( "NOVEMBER" );
int monthNumber = m.getValue();
```

This number plus the day-of-month number can be used to get a `MonthDay` object and used in a manner seen in code below.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( monthNumber , dayOfMonthNumber );
```

## ISO 8601

Store a recurring anniversary as a combined month-day value in a text data-type using standard ISO 8601 format: `--MM-DD`. That is the standard date format using a hyphen in place of the year, `YYYY-MM-DD`. Benefits of this format include bring unambiguous with other date-time formats, and sorting alphabetically is also chronological.

## `MonthDay`

The java.time class `MonthDay` represents this month-day value without a year and without a time zone. This class also knows how to generate and parse strings in that standard format described above.

```
String mdString = myResultSet.getString( … );
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( mdString );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Now get today’s date. Doing so requires a time zone as for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

## `LocalDate`

From that we can extract a date-only value.

```
LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate();
```

Get the current year so we might determine the birthday.

```
int year = today.atYear();
LocalDate birthday= md.atYear( year );
```

That birthday may be in the past, and we want the future.

```
if( ! birthday.isAfter( today ) ) {
    birthday = birthday.plusYears( 1 );
}
```

## `Duration`

Get the span of time between now and that future birthday, create a `Duration`. Apparently your alarm system needs milliseconds. So we need time-of-day. We will go with first moment of the day here. But you probably want a later time-of-day than midnight to fire an alarm!

```
ZonedDateTime alarm = birthday.atStartOfDay();
Duration d = Duration.between( now , alarm );
long millis = d.toMillis();
```

## Android

Much of the java.time functionality was back-ported to Java 6 & 7 the ThreeTen-Backport project. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project.

## Tips

Do not call a day-of-month a "date" as it is ambiguous. Follow the naming seen in the java.time classes.

Do not store a month as an English name. Simpler to store an integer 1-12 for January-December. And in your Java code, use the `Month` enum objects rather than text or numbers.

Comment: But month is display notification class check my image above so and how to implement this code in my code @Basil Bourque

Comment: I cannot understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
String peopleDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_DATE));
            String peopleMonth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_MONTH));
            String peopleYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_YEAR));
```

you are getting the above values as String (cursor.getString()), are these defined as string or int?, Can you post the Create table query.

Comment: I have not create table i have get value from database direct @Ankit Dubey

Answer (score 0):

Lots of confusion in your share code like:

```
String peopleImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_IMAGE));
            String peopleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_NAME));

            String peopleDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_DATE));
            String peopleMonth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_MONTH));
            String peopleYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_YEAR));

            People people = new People();

            people.setPeopleImage(peopleImage);
            people.setPeopleName(peopleName);

            people.setDate(peopleDate);
            people.setMonth(peopleMonth);
            people.setYear(peopleYear);

            peoples.add(people);
```

** You setting lots of value but your People class has only :**

```
public class People implements Serializable {

 private String month, date;

  public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}
```

**So i will suggest you to share People class full and table description.**