# How to pass id instead of position using recyclerView in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have pass position in recyclerView click but some kind of problem pass to position to display wrong data so how can i pass people id in recyclerView.

**I m new in android programming**

**recyclerView Item Click**

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    buildCustomAdapter = new BuildCustomAdapter(this, peopleList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    buildCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(buildCustomAdapter);
buildCustomAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new BuildCustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        detailPeople(position);
    }
});

private void detailPeople(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("peopleID", position);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Model.class**

```
public class People implements Serializable {
    private String peopleImage;
    private String peopleName;
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPeopleName(String peopleName) {
        this.peopleName = peopleName;
    }

    public String getPeopleName() {
        return peopleName;
    }

    public void setPeopleImage(String peopleImage) {
        this.peopleImage = peopleImage;
    }

    public String getPeopleImage() {
        return peopleImage;
    }
}
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class BuildCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuildCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private List<People> peopleList;
private List<People> peopleListCopy;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
private Context mContext;

public BuildCustomAdapter(Context context, List<People> buildList) {
    mContext = context;
    this.peopleList = buildList;
    this.peopleListCopy = new ArrayList<>();
    peopleListCopy.addAll(buildList);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.build_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    People people = peopleList.get(position);

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(people.getPeopleImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    holder.ivPeopleImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    holder.tvPersonName.setText(people.getPeopleName());

    holder.button.setSelected(people.getStatus() == 1);
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new onSelectListener(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return peopleList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView tvPersonName;
    public Button button;
    public CircularImageView ivPeopleImage;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mContext = itemView.getContext();
        ivPeopleImage = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPerson);
        tvPersonName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addbn);
        tvPersonName.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivPeopleImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null)
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            List<People> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < peopleListCopy.size(); i++) {
                if ((peopleListCopy.get(i).getPeopleName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    People peopleName = peopleListCopy.get(i);
                    filterList.add(peopleName);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;

        } else {
            results.count = peopleListCopy.size();
            results.values = peopleListCopy;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        peopleList = (List<People>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


private class onSelectListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    int mPosition;

    public onSelectListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        People people = peopleList.get(mPosition);
        view.setSelected(!view.isSelected());
        people.setStatus(view.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}
**Next Activity to get intent**

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        int peopleID = bundle.getInt("peopleID");
        peopleList.clear();

        BuildDataa();
        People peopleDetailsObj = peopleList.get(peopleID);
}
```

Comment: From where do you get the data for displaying in a ListView?

Comment: use getTag() for recycleView, instead of getId()/getPosition()

Comment: please post your buildCustomAdapter code.

Comment: okay i will share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mOnItemClickListener != null)
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
}
```

to

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mOnItemClickListener != null)
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, peopleList.get(getPosition()).getId());
}
```

in your adapter. And change signature of method onItemClick from

```
onItemClick(View v, int position)
```

to

```
onItemClick(View v, String id)
```

and use this to get People according to ID

```
  People peopleDetailsObj=null;
  for(People ple:peopleList)
  {
    if(ple.getId().equals(peopleID)){
  peopleDetailsObj=ple;
     break;
   }}
```

Comment: yaa pass the id i have get the intent in this line  People peopleDetailsObj = peopleList.get(peopleID); peopleId is 0 how to solve it

Comment: You've to replace People peopleDetailsObj = peopleList.get(peopleID) with the above code

Comment: Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int peopleID = bundle.getInt("peopleID");
            peopleList.clear();

            BuildDataa();
            People people =null;
            for (People ple : peopleList) {
                if (ple.getId().equals(peopleID)) {
                    people = ple;
                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: please change int peopleID = bundle.getInt("peopleID");  to String peopleID = bundle.getString("peopleID");

Comment: sorry i forgot it it's my mistake done boss @brijesh kumar

Comment: plz cheak my another qe:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123215/how-to-get-date-and-month-column-using-object-model-database-in-android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126579/discussion-between-jaydeep-dhamecha-and-brijesh-kumar).

Comment: sry in this qu:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211491/how-to-set-date-and-month-wise-notification-list-android

Comment: hello Brijesh kumar one prob in your example.

Comment: id and people id is match but after i search to people this time same position getting ? position to to pass id

Comment: suppose first time display 50 list okay this time match both id okay after i search i have getting 20 list after i click recyclerview this time wrong data getting..

Comment: for(People ple:peopleList)
  {
    if(ple.getId().equals(peopleID)){
  peopleDetailsObj=ple;
     break;
   }}People Object null error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126831/discussion-between-brijesh-kumar-and-jaydeep-dhamecha).

Answer (score 0):

Take the id from position.

```
String id=peopleList.get(position).getId();
detailPeople(id);
```

Pass that id in your method and you are done.

Comment: Add the clicklistner inside the adapter. Make root layout id then on that layout id put click listner inside bindview. It will work...you can try....I use like this...only...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use position to get People object from ArrayList. Change detailPeople() method with below code.

```
private void detailPeople(int position) {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddDetail.class);
intent.putExtra("peopleID", peopleList.get(position).getId());
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("id", peopleList.get(position).getId());
```